# The last statement in a 'do' construct must be an expression : is there any indentation error

Tags: haskell

```
import Data.ByteString as B
import Data.ByteString.Internal as I
import Data.Bits
main = do input <- getLine
      let bs = B.pack input
      let intermediatebs  =  unfoldrN ((B.length bs)*2) unfld 0
      where unfld i
      |Prelude.rem i 2 == 0 = Just (top4 $ B.index bs (i/2) , i+1)
      |otherwise =  Just (bottom4 $ B.index bs (i/2) , i+1)
      top4bits x = shiftR x 4
      bottom4bits x = x .&. 0x0F
      top4 x = convertASCIIword8 $ top4bits x
      bottom4 x = convertASCIIword8 $ bottom4bits x
      convertASCIIword8 x
      |x <= 9 = I.c2w '0' + x
      |otherwise = I.c2w 'A' + (x-10)
      let outputbs = B.map I.w2c $ intermediatebs
      in do putStrLn (outputbs)
```

i am getting this compilation error
The last statement in a 'do' construct must be an expression:
    let intermediatebs = unfoldrN ((B.length bs) * 2) unfld 0

Comment: It looks like you have three `let` but only one `in`. That's not going to end well. And what's with the mixture of `let` and `where` bindings?

Comment: @HenningMakholm The first two `let`s are inside the `do`-block and don't need an `in`.

Comment: The main problems here are (a) indentation errors (b) using where where let might be clearer, but mainly and most glaringly (c) trying to do everything inside a single main. It's ugly and hard to debug. Please please please rewrite your code into separate functions until you can write main = fmap myProcessingFunction getLine >>= putStrLn

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's hard to see exactly what you want here. It is possible to make your code parse with only indentation changes:

```
import Data.ByteString as B
import Data.ByteString.Internal as I
import Data.Bits
main = do
  input <- getLine
  let bs = B.pack input
  let intermediatebs  =  unfoldrN ((B.length bs)*2) unfld 0
       where
        unfld i
          | Prelude.rem i 2 == 0 = Just (top4 $ B.index bs (i/2) , i+1)
          | otherwise =  Just (bottom4 $ B.index bs (i/2) , i+1)
        top4bits x = shiftR x 4
        bottom4bits x = x .&. 0x0F
        top4 x = convertASCIIword8 $ top4bits x
        bottom4 x = convertASCIIword8 $ bottom4bits x
        convertASCIIword8 x
          | x <= 9 = I.c2w '0' + x
          | otherwise = I.c2w 'A' + (x-10)
  let outputbs = B.map I.w2c $ intermediatebs
  putStrLn (outputbs)
```

although it won't compile due to ambiguous `getLine` and `putStrLn` occurrences. You may want to `import qualified` where appropriate. Key observations:

- Do-blocks, let-blocks etc. start from the left edge of *the first thing inside* them, regardless of where the keyword is itself. E.g.

  ```
  do x
     y
  -- ^ because of where the x is, all future lines have to line up with it

  let x = ...
      y = ...
  -- ^ if you have code appearing left of here, the let-block ends
  ```

  As a consequence, I often give `do` and `where` their own line before starting a block. In the example I gave above, you can see that even if I moved the do-block into a function with a longer or shorter name, the indentation wouldn't change.
- Lines in the same block that start indented are a continuation of the previous line. Guards are a continuation so need to be indented, likewise `where` for a let assignment needs to be indented further than the assignment itself.
- The `in do` at the end of your block was redundant, so I removed it (alternatively, just indenting it would have worked too).

Answer (score 1):

The error message is not caused by an indentation error so much as an ordering error. You seem to have inserted the `where`-block in the middle of your `do`-block. That does not work. The entire `do`-block, including the final expression, should come before the `where` block.

That said, you do have indentation error in your definitions inside your `where`-block: you need to indent the pattern guards.

Comment: Indeed, it is *not* easy to see what OP intented here. The where clause is supposed include everything including convertASCIIword, but why should the compiler stop there when the subsequent text has the same indendation. But if the last let is included in the where, then the last line of the outer do is indeed a let, and this is an error.

Answer (score 1):

Your outer `do` consists only of `input <- getLine` since the following token `let` is already less indended than `input` (which makes no sense anyway, but ....)

Perhaps you mean:

```
do  input <- getLine
    let ....
    let .....   where 
          unfld ....
```

But one can only guess. Use indendation to make clear what items belong together, and what items are subitems of others. The style above rather obscures this. Also, you shouldn't write

```
foo x y z
| ..... =
```

because the compiler would see

```
foo x y z; | ... =
```